# Knockout binding data from select to button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

[Fiddle for reference.](http://jsfiddle.net/JZCWE/)

What I'm attempting to do is create a dropdown containing a list of projects. This dropdown houses 2 categories of projects: favorite and non-favorite (designated by a 1 or 0), the favorite projects being in an opt-group.

```
<select data-bind="foreach: $root.favorites, value: project_id, event: {change: console.log('changed') }" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
    <!-- ko if: $data == 1 -->
    <optgroup data-bind="attr: {label: 'Favorites'}, foreach: $root.projects">
        <!-- ko if: favorite() == "1" -->
        <option data-bind="text: project_name, value: project_id"></option>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </optgroup>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: $data == 0 -->
            <option data-divider="true"></option>
        <!-- ko foreach: $root.projects -->
            <!-- ko if: favorite() == 0 -->
            <option data-bind="text: project_name, value: project_id"></option>
            <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</select>
```

When a 'favorited' project is selected, the button to the left of the select should have a class of `favorited`, and the class should be removed if a project that is not a favorite is selected.

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-bind="click: , css: { favorited: true }" style="padding: 0px 7px; font-size: 20px; margin-left: 10px; color: #cccccc;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" style="padding-top: 5px;"></span></button>
```

(the code currently just sets favorited on the button by default, just to show what it should look like)

When the button to the left of the select is clicked, it should also toggle the `favorite` property of the selected project -- 1 if it's now a favorite, and a 0 if it is no longer a favorite.

So, my questions are:

1. Is there a better way to set up the select than I have here?
2. How do I change the class of the button based on the `favorite` status of the selected project?
3. How do I toggle the `favorite` status of the selected project when the button is clicked?
4. In general, is there a better way to write all of this? (fairly new to Knockout still)

I also have full control of the data coming in, so that can be modified if needed to make a cleaner/simpler solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `"Not sure how to do this in Knockout"` is not a good title, the bit in brackets would likely be enough though... on it's own

Comment: Edited to be (hopefully) better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [my implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/zR8ga/).

Edit: [modifed fiddle based on comments](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/kue2a/)

To reduce a couple of the `== 0`, `== 1` checks. Turn the favorite property/attribute into a boolean. Since the css is driven by `favorite` of a project, let the value of the `<select>` be an actual project object. Using knockout aliasing it looks like

`foreach: {data: $root.projects, as: 'projectAlias'}"`

now we can properly use the `selectedProject` variable in your model. Make sure to remove the `undefined` initializer and set it to an observable: `self.selectedProject = ko.observable();`

Now the css binding can "listen" to changes on your selection. You can achieve this several different ways. I chose to use a `computed`.

```
self.cssToggle = ko.computed(function() {
    if(self.selectedProject()){
        return self.selectedProject().favorite();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Bind it `css: { favorited: cssToggle}`.
To enable/implement the click functionality of the favorite button, bind a method `click: toggleFavorite` and provide it in the viewmodel:

```
self.toggleFavorite = function () {
    var currentState = self.selectedProject().favorite();
    self.selectedProject().favorite(!currentState);
}
```

At this point, you should have the behavior you desire. I think I covered everything I changed, reference the fiddle in case I missed something. It may be possible to reduce the `foreach` bindings to a single pass of `projects`. I may revisit that as I "fiddled" with this while waiting on something else.

Comment: This looks great, thanks! Two questions, though: 1. How would I set the selected project in the select when the select builds (currently being passed in with the entry data as project_id)? 2. (may be directly related to #1) When I un-favorite a favorited project, the project is un-favorited, but then the select goes to the first element instead of staying on the same project that was un-favorited. Any idea why?

Comment: Issue #2 occurs due to the dereference of the observable `self.selectedProject().favorite(!currentState);` when toggling favorite. The communication between the data-bind and the js observable is severed. Couple of solutions available, one is to manually force the UI update with a `self.selectedProject.valueHasMutated();` call at the end of `toggleFavorite` function.

Comment: Oh wow, this looks great! Thanks a bunch! The divider won't be a problem in the app, I'm using the selectpicker plugin for bootstrap to convert that to an unselectable element.

Comment: For issue #1, you can modify the initialization to take in a project object or iterate over the projects and find the object based on the id. Once you have a project make sure you call `entriesModel.selectedProject(intialProjectSelection)` after your `ko.applyBindings(entriesModel)`. See [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/kue2a/) with both issues addressed. I also removed the foreach from select.

Comment: In my full code the plan is to store the initial project_id in a variable in the TimeEntriesModel, then in the map of projects do an if to test if the project that was just made has the same ID as the initial project_id , and if so set it. Untested as of now, but I think that should do what I need it to.

Comment: It seems that I did something silly and left out a key part of my viewmodels (that part being an entire viewmodel). I actually have an entry viewmodel which handles the project, favorite state, etc. Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nfmpg/ -- Any idea how I could implement the initial project part with it set up like this?

Comment: What is the purpose of entries? How do they relate to projects? Basically what do you need that data to do for you or how would you like to use it?

Comment: The TimeEntriesModel is meant mainly to hold 2 datasets -- entries and projects. Each EntryViewModel has 7 EntryDataViewModel that it holds (representing days of the week), and each EntryViewModel has a project associated with it (the project assigned to that entry). So, when the data is loaded, the TimeEntriesModel takes all the entries and projects and makes fills their respective models with their data, each entry is populated with the entry data (including the associated project). This works fine for anything but the initial load/reload of the page because only the project ID is passed in.

Comment: have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/Z5Ha3/) One option is to iterate over the data and set the `selectedProject` variable.

Comment: Looks like that did it. It's all working like I need it to now, thanks!